# How to run the same pandas manipulations on a batch of CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am running the following code on individual CSV files:

```
import pandas as pd

header_names = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6']

df = pd.read_csv('some.csv', delimiter= "|", skiprows=1, names=header_names)

df['column2'].replace(['bad', 'worse'],['good', 'better'],inplace =True)

df.to_csv('new.csv', index=False)
```

How can I run this code on a batch of files instead of changing the code for each file name?

Edit: If all of the CSV files I want to modify are in a single folder would that make this easier?

Comment: do you want to append all the CSV to new.csv?

Comment: use glob to get a list of csv files, then iterate over it

Comment: There two easy ways. You can get the list of files then loop over them. You can also use `Dask` to read all the files at the same time, then do the manipulation once.

Comment: @gtomer I need to modify the existing CSVs then save the modified CSV as a new file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this logic for multiple files:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def my_function(source_file, target_suffix):
    header_names = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6']    
    df = pd.read_csv(source_file, delimiter= "|", skiprows=1, names=header_names)    
    df['column2'].replace(['bad', 'worse'],['good', 'better'],inplace =True)
    # Generating output file name based on the input file name, and the provided suffix
    target_file = source_file.replace('.csv', '') + '_output_' + str(target_suffix) + '.csv' 
    df.to_csv(target_file, index=False)

# Define list of input_file    
file_names = []

# Set the directory of your files
directory = os.path.join("c:\\","path")
# Locate the input csv file
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           file_names.append(file)

# Looping on the input file names and their indexes using enumerate
for i, source_file in enumerate(file_names):
    # Call the function on the file name, and passing file index as the suffix
    my_function(source_file, i)
```

Comment: Could I import a folder so I don't have to type out the file name of every .csv I want to modify as well as the output name?

Comment: @canigan updated code, now it both finds the input csv files and outputs with unique names

Answer (score 1):

As answered by gtomer and Aviv Yaniv, I'd like to extend this answer as how are you gonna get the name of the files which are in your target directory.
You can use the following code to get the names of csv files in the directory.

```
csv_files=[]
import os 
directory=os.path.join("Path to the directory")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            print(file)
            csv_files.append(pd.read_csv(file,error_bad_lines=False))
```

and the you can run your logic inside a for loop iterating over each file.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop between you files:

```
files = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv']
agg_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter= "|", skiprows=1, names=header_names)
    df['column2'].replace(['bad', 'worse'],['good', 'better'],inplace =True)
    agg_df = agg_df.append(df)
agg_df.to_csv('new.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

header_names = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6']

df = dd.read_csv("./directory/*.csv", delimiter= "|", skiprows=1, names=header_names)
df['column2'] = df['column2'].replace(['bad', 'worse'],['good', 'better'])
df.to_csv("./directory/export-*.csv")
```

There's a lot of ways to change the export name. The * in the `read_csv` will read all files with a .csv ending. The * on the `to_csv` will number all the different files when they get exported. No need to use for loops using this method.

Comment: I really want to try this out, but I don't have dask installed and when I try to install it I keep getting a write permission error so I'm going to have to try a solution that doesn't involve it